# How do I setup an import for the Do Not Email field?

Tags: import, field-mapping

I am a newby.

Why would 'Do not Email' not be checked even though my import mapped and imported without error?

It says it didn't have an error, but it must have imported with an error. I was able to force an import error message with data like "Checked".

The import completed without error when the Do not Email column is Y. I think it even worked when it is YES. But the import hasn't actually changed the contacts' data.

**How do I set up the import correctly for the 'Do Not Email' field?**

Thanks.

Johnny

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to CiviCRM!

For the import of Boolean fields (yes/no, true/false, check boxes, etc.) the correct syntax is 0 for no or false and 1 for yes or true. **Use 1 instead of Y or YES**, and it should work for you.

Be aware that your imports thus far may have created NULL values in the database. See this question and answer for reference: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/7396/105

You'll want to check your database or have your admin check those values to make sure you've got 1s and 0s instead of NULL.